# How to make inductive step for a Fibonacci proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification, induction, fibonacci-numbers

I have to prove $F^2_{n−1} = F^2_n + F^2_{n−1}$ for any $n >=1$ by induction (for the Fibonacci sequence).

For the basis step, I have:

$n = 1; $  $F_{(1)-1} = F^2_{(1)} + F^2_{(1)-1}   ->$

$ 1 = 1^2+ 0$

As the base case holds, we can then assume that $n=k$:

$F_{2(k)-1} = F^2_{(k)} + F^2_{(k)-1} $

Next, this has to be proven for k + 1:

$F_{2(k+1)-1} = F^2_{(k+1)} + F^2_{(k+1)-1} $

I know that you have to somehow used the statement derived on the LHS of the equation in the previous step ( i.e. $F_{2(k)-1}$ ) when proving for $k+1$, but I'm not really sure how to apply the logic here since I've normally seen it used in cases where there is a summation on the LHS.

I currently have worked this out:

$F_{2(k+1) - 1} = F^2_{k + 1} + F^2_{(k+1) -1} ->$

$F_{2k + 1} = F^2_{(k+1)} + F^2_k$

and with some manipulation (I was thinking), you could factor out the $F^2$ from both terms on the RHS resulting in this:

$F^2_{(2k +1)}$, but even after doing this, the term on the LHS is:$F_{2k + 1}$ so even though both sides are similar, they differ by the squared term on the LHS.

Is my logic wrong in the inductive step? If so, how should I go about the proof?